# C# Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word SaveAs2 method - source

Tags: c#, .net, dll, ms-word, ms-office

is it possibile to access and inspect the code of this method and if yes...where and how?
I'd like to know if it's possible to understand the logic of the conversion eg from .docx to .pdf and possibly try to port it to another language.

Thanks

Comment: please list me any open source libraries (excluding libre office / open office) that does exactly that: do an hi-fidelity (meaning keeping exaclty all the formatting, etc... exactly as exporting manually from MS Word to PDF) and that can run from a Linux system.

Comment: nothing will ensure that, because in theory, ms word is not opensource and microsoft make money by it.

Comment: so the reply to your question following your statement:
"there must be some open source .net library for this"
is "I don't know any of them."
?

Comment: i said that before you said the word **exactly** which only microsoft can  guarantee

Comment: cool. 
You don't have any answers to my original questions. I haven't asked any advice for something similar like achieving a format conversion.

tnx

Comment: you're right, i did not answer, i only write some comments. then what. did you get your answer now?

Comment: @Luke: note that asking for tools or other off-site resources is not allowed here. Generally you won't get an answer to such requests. As in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The assemblies containing that code are in the `Microsoft.Office.*.Implementation` assemblies in your GAC. I guess that code will just call their respective functions in the Office code base, which is in C++. You have to dive into those DLLs to find its implementation there.

I do have to warn you though: reverse engineering code and reusing that for your own is considered breach of copyright in most countries...

Comment: tnx. how can I access/download those sources or assemblies?

I'm on OS X 10.11.6 with MS office installed?

Comment: In the GAC of a Windows machine with Office installed.

Comment: what is a GAC ..?

Comment: Global Assembly Cache.